# How to compile framework for Mac Catalyst on Xcode 12?

Tags: swift, mac-catalyst, aws-sdk-ios

I have been trying to compile the **aws-sdk-ios** for Mac Catalyst but I wasn't successful yet. Below there is the script that I use to compile for `armv7` and `x86_64` (simulator).

```sh
# Build .a files
xcodebuild ARCHS="i386 x86_64" \
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
    -configuration Debug \
    -project "${project_path}" \
    -target "${project_name}" \
    -sdk iphonesimulator \
    SYMROOT=$(PWD)/builtFramework 

xcodebuild ARCHS="armv7  arm64" \
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
    -configuration Release \
    -project "${project_path}" \
    -target "${project_name}" \
    -sdk iphoneos  \
    SYMROOT=$(PWD)/builtFramework
```

This correctly compiles the project and results into these folders:

[image: Folders]

I tried to compile the project for Mac Catalyst with multiple variations of the code below (based in multiple examples on the internet):

```sh
xcodebuild ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
    -project "${project_path}" \
    -target "${project_name}" \
    -destination "generic/platform=macOS,variant=Mac Catalyst,name=Any Mac"
    SYMROOT=$(PWD)/builtFramework
```

This seems to not create any `Release-maccatalyst` folder or anything else, even adding these flags:

```sh
SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES SUPPORTS_MACCATALYST=YES
```

Or these:

```sh
ARCHS="x86_64" VALID_ARCHS="x86_64"
```

*(Also tried with `x86_64h`, no luck)*

With the `ARCHS` flags above, the compilation fails with these errors:

[image]

I am not sure what I need to do to compile the project, anyone could please help me to find the correct script to create the `.framework` for Catalyst?

Regards,
Pedro

Comment: Catalyst is an emulator of iOS on macOS - you just build framework as for iOS and it will be used by iOS application in Catalyst environment.

Comment: @Asperi Shoudn't the framework be inside a folder like `Release-maccatalyst`? How I will be able to create the fat lib with this configuration?

Comment: No dedicated binary. Just iOS+macOS, as usual.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You are helping a lot so far. I have the script here in hands, could you please check if this is correct? You might want to copy it and paste as the answer so I can close this issue: https://github.com/T-Pro/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/Scripts/package_sdk.sh#L57-L64

Comment: @PedroPauloAmorim hey, did you found a solution/working script? thanks